# 4/96 imbalanced but all metrics above .95

Tags: machine-learning, class-imbalance, f1score

I'm working with some severely imbalanced dataset where my 1 class represents 4% of the data in a binary classification problem.
I have about 10M rows and developed a model that outputs +.95 in accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score, f1_score, roc_auc_score.
I always heard that the data needs to be balanced otherwise, the model will be biased towards the 0 class. In the case where the model has a good f1, is that still the case? In my problem, what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Accuracy score is very misleading in imbalanced data sets. Your model can always output the class 0, and will get 96% accuracy for your data set. Precision and recall (and F1-score, obviously) are dependant on a probability threshold. How do you determine when your model outputs a positive (class 1) prediction?

Though, if F1 is high, it means both your precision and recall are also high, and if the AUC is also high, then you have a really good model.

If you are not absolutely sure, then I recommend trying out a custom metric, like: `Rank of the lowest scoring positive (class 1) sample`.

Also, double-check that the scores you are reporting are indeed for the positive - minority class, and not for the negative (majority), could be that you've overlooked that one. You can always provide some code snippets or results to make your question more clear.

Comment: Tbh I thought I would have to find the right decision threshold after training the model but it outputted those results out of the box. The threshold was at .5 which I should change. Thanks for suggesting the last point, I thought about it too when I saw the results were too good but the labels are good and the positive class has 4% of the volume.